# Programs not Executing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, teamspeak

So one day randomly a month ago all of my programs that I installed stopped opening when I clicked them. I figured out how to manually run Minecraft since it is a jar file, but other programs not so much.

For example, my Teamspeak client requires you to use a .sh file but when I double click it, nothing happens. Same with a few other programs but my main concern is the Teamspeak client. Any advice?

P.S It is Linux Ubuntu installed onto my HP Chromebook '14

Comment: try to update + upgrade the system.

Comment: Try opening a terminal and executing sh

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your environment has been erased... Try:

1. Open a terminal window (I suppose that works, else you couldn't have called Minecraft).
2. Type a system command, say `ls`. This should show the directory list. I also suspect that to be working
3. Type a command of an installed program, `java`...
4. Type the name of one of the programs that *don't* work, and check the screen for error messages. (If there are any, report them here) Eg. type the name of the Teamspeak `.sh` file.
5. If, in 4., there is a message about the *program* not being found, type `echo $PATH` and check if in the long list, separated by `:`, there is a mention of where your program is installed.

EDIT: If your path is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` then the OS will look in

```
/usr/local/bin,
/usr/bin,
/bin,
/usr/local/games
/usr/games
```

If your games is not in one of these directories it won't work. So, select one of the programs/games that doesn't work, type the name:

```
your_games<enter>
```

Does it start or not? If not, is there any message?

Comment: Alright, so after I typed in echo $PATH it lists /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
What do I do from this point? Sorry I got a bit confused at this point.

Comment: I've added a few more instructions to the answer.